# Союз как в указании на произношение, перевод

Tags: союзы

Допустимы ли следующие выражения в устной речи?

> Контент произносится как "Контэнт".
>
> На русский это слово переводится как "метро".

Допустим ли союз "как" в таких выражениях?

Comment: "как" это не предлог, а союз, вводящий сравнение.

Comment: Союз "как" допустим в любых сравнительных выражениях так как является их основой.

Comment: Можно ли приведённые выражения назвать сравнительными? Не сравнивается же слово со своим звучанием...